# how can i download and integrate BBM SDK to my current application

Tags: blackberry

How can I add BBM SDK to my current blackberry project , can any one please provide download link ,

```
    My Target is to add Blackberry Pin programatically to Blackberry Messanger.
```

Answer (score -1):

We cannot add the PIN to BBM Contacts,programmtically ,We dont have any control over BBM Contacts adding or deleting programmatically.

I  know  we can invoke BBM pplication from ours,but i dont know whether we can have predefined BBM Pin for invitation.But we cannot do all the things programmatically,You may need user prompt to do this sort of things

Here is [link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry%20Messenger%20Social%20Platform%20SDK)

Comment: hi,how to launch BBM programmatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538301/programmatically-share-the-text-in-bbm-blackberry,can you help me how to solve this-thanks